# is singular with custom post type but without id

Tags: wordpress

I want to echo some text on all custom post types from the same group.

The following is_singular code successfully displays the text on all CPTs:

```
if (is_singular () ) {
   echo 'something'; }
```

The following is_singular code with the plugin's CPT identifier successfully displays the text on just one specific instance of that CPT group:

```
if (is_singular ('tu_result_1836') ) {
   echo 'something'; }
```

To apply it to all CPTs from the tu_result group, if I try 'tu_result' or 'tu_result_' instead of 'tu_result_1836', it no longer works. Do I need to use a wildcard function, e.g. 'tu_result_*'? Or is it incorrect to use is_singular here. I have also tried all of the above combinations with is_single.
Hopefully someone can help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following works for you? :

```
if( is_singular() && strpos(get_post_type(), 'tu_result_') !== false ){}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to handle what you are tying to do:

**Note:** All information below assumes you've named your custom post type `tu_result`.  If not, adjust as necessary.

First, you could use the [Template Heirarchy System](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) to your advantage, and create a template for your `tu_result`.  If it doesn't exist, create it - name it `single-tu_result.php`, and it will be the template that WordPress automatically displays for any single posts that are `tu_result` types.

Second, you could extend your functionality slightly using the [get_post_type()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/) function, like so:

```
if ( is_singular() ) {
    if ( 'tu_result' == get_post_type() ) {
        echo 'This will show ONLY for the tu_result post types!';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and educational explanation. I was able to get the first solution working but I'm struggling with the second.